# Airflow multiple jobs with same schedules and different schedules

Tags: airflow

1. I have 5 jobs which run every 5 minutes. So is there a way to combine these in a single DAG ? Or I should go on creating new DAGS for each of such jobs. This will en up in enormous dags with just 1 job in it.
   These jobs are not related to each other
2. The second question is, I have some jobs that are dependent on each other but have different schedules. every 5 min, daily, only few days in a week, every 5 min 9am to 5pm and every 15 min from 5pm to 9am. How do I configure tasks with different scheduling times in a single DAG?

   schedule_interval='5 00 00 * *',